# Preservation of completeness through a continous onto mapping

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X_{1},d_{1})$ and $(X_{2},d_{2})$ be metric spaces and $f: X_{1} \to X_{2}$ be a continuous onto map such that
$$   d_{1}(x,y) \leq d_{2}(f(x),f(y)) \hspace{2mm} \forall\phantom{i}x,y \in X_{1}$$
(a) Prove or disprove: If $(X_{1},d_{1})$ is complete, then $(X_{2},d_{2})$ is complete.

*My attempt*, but I lose confidence towards the end. May someone help clear this up, or offer comments?

> Suppose $(X_{1},d_{1})$ is complete. Then, every Cauchy sequence in $(X_{1},d_{1})$ converges in the space. Let $\{x_{n}\} \to \hat{x}$ be such a sequence. Then, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d_{1}(x_{n},x_{m}) < \varepsilon$ when $n,m > N$. By continuity of $f$, we have that for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta = \delta_{\varepsilon}$ such that $d_{2}(f(x_{n}),f(x_{m})) < \varepsilon$ when $d_{1}(x_{n},x_{m}) < \delta_{\varepsilon}$. Choose $\varepsilon = \delta_{\varepsilon}$. Then, $d_{1}(x_{n},x_{m}) < \varepsilon = \delta_{\varepsilon} \implies d_{2}(f(x_{n}),f(x_{m})) < \varepsilon$. Thus,
>   $$
>     d_{1}(x_{n},x_{m}) \leqslant d_{2}(f(x_{n}),f(x_{m})) < \varepsilon
> $$
>   thus as $m,n > N$, it follows that $f(x_{n})$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(X_{2},d_{2})$. Since $f$ is continuous and onto, it follows that $f(x_{i}) \in X_{2}$ so the limit of $\{f(x_{n})\}$ is in $(X_{2},d_{2})$. Thus, $(X_{2},d_{2})$ is complete.

Comment: You want to show that $(X_2,d_2)$ is complete: for this, start with a Cauchy sequence $(y_n)$ in $(X_2,d_2)$ and show that it converges! What you showed is that the image by $f$ of a Cauchy sequence of $(X_1,d_1)$ is a sequence that converges in $(X_2,d_2)$.

Comment: Ok, how does this tie-in to the hypothesis of "If $(X_{1},d_{1})$ is complete, then... "?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment; but start with a Cauchy sequence $(y_n)$ in $(X_2,d_2)$. Then maybe use surjectivity of $f$ to obtain a sequence $(x_n)$ of elements of $X_1$ such that $y_n=f(x_n)$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $(y_n)$ is Cauchy, there exists $N$ such that $\forall p,q\geq N$, $d_2(y_p,y_q)<\varepsilon$, i.e., $d_2(f(x_p),f(x_q))<\varepsilon$, and using the hypothesis on $f$, $d_1(x_p,x_q)<\varepsilon$. Hence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy in $(X_1,d_1)$. Now I know you can finish the proof `:)`.

Comment: You have it backwards. You have to show that a Cauchy sequence in  $X_2$ has a limit, not that a convergent sequence in $X_1$ maps to a convergent sequence in $X_2$ ,which is true regardless of completeness, by the continuity of $f$.

Comment: Many thanks for these comments. How is this looking? Let $\{y_{n}\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $(X_{2},d_{2})$. By surjectivity of $f$, there is a sequence in $X_{1}$, say $\{x_{n}\}$, such that $\{y_{n}\} = \{f(x_{n})\}$. Since $\{y_{n}\}$ is Cauchy, then, for all $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists an $N \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $d_{2}(y_{n},y_{m}) < \varepsilon \iff d_{2}(f(x_{n}),f(x_{m})) < \varepsilon$ for all $n, m \geqslant N$. And, by assumption, $d_{1}(x_{n},x_{m}) < d_{2}(f(x_{n}),f(x_{m})) < \varepsilon$ for $m,m \geqslant N$, so $\{x_{n}\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X_{1}$. (con't...)

Comment: Since $(X_{1},d_{1})$ is complete, then $\{x_{n}\}$ converges to some $\hat{x} \in X_{1}$ and so $\{y_{n}\} \to f(\hat{x})$. Thus, we have that $(X_{2},d_{2})$ is a complete metric space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(b_n)_{n\in N}$ be a $d_2$-Cauchy sequence in $X_2.$ For each $n\in N,$ choose $a_n\in X_1$ such that $f(a_n)=b_n.$ $$\text {We have  }\quad \lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{m>n}d_1(a_n,a_m)\leq \lim_{n\to \infty}\sup_{m>n}d_2(b_n,b_m)=0.$$ Therefore $(a_n)_{n\in N}$ is a $d_1$-Cauchy sequence in $X_1.$ Since $d_1$ is complete, the sequence $(a_n)_{n \in N}$ converges to a limit point $a\in X_1.$ Since $f$ is continuous, the sequence $(f(a_n))_{n\in N}=(b_n)_{n\in N}$ converges in $X_2$ to $f(a).$

Remark.In a metric space $X$, a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in N}$ converges to $a\in X$ iff whenever $U$ is a nbhd of $a,$ the set $\{n:a_n\not \in U\}$ is finite....

So let $V$ be any nbhd of $f(a)$ in $X_2$ and let $U$ be a nbhd of $a$ in $X_1$ such that $f U\subset V.$ ($U$ exists because $f$ is continuous.) Then $\{n: f(a_n)\not \in V\}\subset \{n:a_n\not \in U\}$, which is finite. So $(f(a_n))_{n\in N}$ converges in $X_2$ to $f(a).$